# Flask/Jinja2 template: Loop with multiple list positions

Tags: python, list, loops, flask, jinja2

---

[Not really sure if the topic makes sense, but didn't found a more meaningful one.]

I've created a template which looks like:

```
{% for x in jobs %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.Ecordov.oovorder }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.ooaname1.split('{}')[0] }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.ooaname2.split('{}')[0] }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.ooazusatz.split('{}')[0] }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I'm getting a specific position in multiple lists, which works quite well.

The problem I'm trying to solve: These lists have up to 16 positions, which I have to render. I could of course copy/paste the above `<tr> </tr>` block 16 times into the template, and edit the line positions, but I'm quite sure that there is a better, more automated, way; however, I wasn't able to find this out on my own up until now.

Could anyone point me into the correct direction?

Thanks for any help and all the best!

Comment: You could use `getattr(x, attr)` to grab the value within the attribute.  Armed with this, you could do something like `for attr in ['ooaname1', 'ooaname2', ...]`, and simply do the rendering with `{{ getattr(x, attr).split(....) }}`.  Ideally you want that list of attributes be stored in your code rather than the template for organization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. In the end I've used the method described by doru. Regarding your last sentence: I fully agree, however, I had problems to inject both the context ("jobs") and the list of attributes into the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for x in jobs %}
    {% for i in range(0, 17) %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.Ecordov.oovorder }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.ooaname1.split('{}')[i] }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.ooaname2.split('{}')[i] }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ x.ooazusatz.split('{}')[i] }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't know how many elements does the list have you have to find it first and use it as the *stop* argument (the second argument of the `range()` function).